# How does orderBy work with $odd and $even in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns both containing items from the same array. I want to achieve the masonry effect since the height of each `.tile` will be different.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="tile" ng-repeat="item in items| orderBy: 'id'" ng-if="$odd">
         <button ng-click="alert($index)"></button>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="tile" ng-repeat="item in items| orderBy: 'id'" ng-if="$even">
         <button ng-click="alert($index)"></button>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Will Angular do the odd-even alternation on the sorted array or the way elements are stored in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is going to alternate on the way the elements are stored in the array. If you want to organize the array I would use .sort() before assigning to Angular $scope. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I don't think that's accurate based on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RCHA77OzySsSUVwpt14o?p=preview). Angular 1.4.x seems to apply the `$odd` and `$even` attributes after the `orderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the trying the code below, it seems that Angular does apply `$odd` and `$even` after sorting based on the `orderBy` filter. However, this would only work correctly in a single `ng-repeat` directive. I would modify your code to look like the following:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("ItemController", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      id: 50
    }, {
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2
    }, {
      id: 5
    }, {
      id: 3
    }];

    $scope.alert = function(idx) {
      console.log(idx);
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="ItemController">
      <div class="tile" ng-repeat="item in items| orderBy: 'id'">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="$odd" ng-click="alert($index)">{{item.id}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-if="$even" ng-click="alert($index)">{{item.id}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

In other words, you should apply the `ng-if` directive to the element inside your `ng-repeat` directive. Depending on what exactly you want to alternate, it might be simpler to use `ng-class` or another directive that allows you to specify conditional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular [`orderBy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#!/) filter returns a copy of the source array.  The `ng-repeat` is applied to the copy.

Your example case will work, but it will create twice as many `$watch` elements, and you might experience odd flickering of the data shifting back and forth between columns if the number of rows changes.  Also, because arrays are 0 based, your rows will be backwards.